# Is MapReduce a possible solution for two lists that have an id in common?

Tags: python, mysql, hadoop

I have a list of 30m entries, containing a unique id and 4 attributes for each entry. In addition to that I have a second list with 10m entries, containing again a uniqe id and 2 other attributes. 
The unique IDs in list 2 are a subset of the IDs in list 1.
I want to combine the two lists to do some analysis.

## Example:

### List 1:

```
ID|Age|Flag1|Flag2|Flag3
------------------------
ucab577|12|1|0|1
uhe4586|32|1|0|1
uhf4566|45|1|1|1
45e45tz|37|1|1|1
7ge4546|42|0|0|1
vdf4545|66|1|0|1
```

### List 2:

```
ID|Country|Flag4|Flag5|Flag6
------------------------
uhe4586|US|0|0|1
uhf4566|US|0|1|1
45e45tz|UK|1|1|0
7ge4546|ES|0|0|1
```

I want to do analysis like:
"How many at the age of 45 have Flag4=1?" Or "What is the age structure of all IDs in US?"

My current approach is to load the two list into separate tables of a relational database and then doing a join.

- Does a MapReduce approach make sense in this case?

  - If yes, how would a MapReduce approach look like?
  - How can I combine the attributes of list 1 with list 2?
- Will it bring any advantages? (Currently I need more than 12 hours for importing the data)

Answer (score 1):

when the files are big hadoops distributed processing helps(faster). once you bring data to hdfs then you can use hive or pig for your query. Both uses hadoop MR for processing,you do not need to write separate code for it . hive is almost sql like. from your query type i guess you can manage with hive. if your queries are more complex then you can consider pig. if you use hive here is the sample steps.

1. load both the files in two separate folder in hdfs.
2. create external tables for both of them and give location to the destination folders.
3. perform join and the query!

`hive> create external table hiveint_r(id string, age int, Flag1 int, Flag2 int, Flag3 int)`

```
> row format delimited
> fields terminated by '|'
> location '/user/root/data/hiveint_r';  (it is in hdfs)
```

table will be automatically populated with data, no need to load it.
similar way create other table, then run the join and query.

```
select a.* from hiveint_l a full outer join hiveint_r b on (a.id=b.id) where b.age>=30 and a.flag4=1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

MapReduce might be overkill for just 30m entries. How you should work really depends on your data. Is is dynamic (e.g. will new entries be added?) If not, just stick with your database, the data is now in it. 30m entries shouldn't take 12 hours to import, it's more likely 12 minutes (you should be able to get 30.000 insert/seconds with 20 byte datasize), so your approach should be to fix your import. You might want to try bulk import, [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html), use transactions and/or generate the index afterwards, try another engine (innodb, MyISAM), ...

You can get just one big table (so you can get rid of the joins when you query which will speed them up) by e.g.

```
Update List1 join List2 on List1.Id = List2.Id 
set List1.Flag4 = List2.Flag4, List1.Flag5 = List2.Flag5, List1.Flag6 = List2.Flag6
```

after adding the columns to List1 of course and after adding the indexes, and you should afterwards add indexes for all your columns.

You can actually combine your data before you import it to mysql by e.g. reading list 2 into a hashmap (Hashmap in c/c++/java, array in php/python) and then generate a new import file with the combined data. It should actually just take you some seconds to read the data. You can even do evaluation here, it is just not that flexible as sql, but if you just have some fixed querys, that might be the fastest approach if your data changes often.

Answer (score 0):

In map-Reduce you can process the two files by using the join  techniques. There are  two types of joins-Map side and reduce side.

Map side join can be efficiently used by using DistributedCache API in which  one file shud be loaded in memory. In you case you can can create a HashMap with key->id and value-> Flag4 and during the map phase you can join the data based on ID. One point shud be noted that the file should be as large so that it can be saved in memory.

If both the files are large go for Reduce join.

First try to load the 2nd file in memory and create Map-side join.

OR you can go for pig. Anyway the pig executes its statements as map-reduce jobs only. But map-reduce is fast as compared to PIG and HIVE.